# Connect opencv to qtcreator

Tags: qt, visual-c++, opencv

I have VC++ & opencv code and I want to design GUI to it using qtcreator.

First of all, I included the libraries to the project and it ran without any errors.

Now, what should I do after this?

How can I add the code into main.cpp file in the project?

should I change every opencv code to Q... like IpImage to QImage?

Comment: This is most likely too broad a question to answer. Sorry to ask, but what is your experience with C++?

Comment: thank you for answer, my experience in C++ is Medium , I mean from my Q. how can add myCode.cpp to mayProject.pro in qtcreator and connect them (connect the code with interface). I am a beginner in qtCreator.Any help , tutorials. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [VS-addin](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in) it will hook the.pro file to a gui editor automatically

Comment: thank you, I install it and when I open project in MVS this error appear:cannot find qmake.Make sure you have specified a Qt version. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

About connecting OpenCV to Qt GUI classes , here is an example code  QtOpenCV [1](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt+Opencv+webcam+viewer?content=89995)  . It takes content ipmage ,IIRC converts into rgb32 and paints it over a QWidget in paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);